# Can the human chin have developed to protect against combat strangles?

Tags: evolution, human-anatomy

Has the mechanical explanation of headlock defense ever been discussed by scientists to explain the chin(protuberantia mentalis)? A mechanical advantage that prevents death and being beaten up by another male would undergo a type of topological optimization that could be measured.

[image]

[image: image1]

Positions where an assailant wraps his arm around a defendant's neck constitute 3/4rs of professional wrestling submissions. It's even more prevailant in amator wrestling where the contestants don't learn conplex arm and leg locks, in children, and in young adults.

When the neck is lowered, arm is barred from the neck, and the commentator shouts"will he manage to keep his chin down"

That kind of defense of the neck with the chin lowered can last 2-3 minutes, after which time the assailant's arms tire and the position changes.

The chin can therefore play a major role in human defense, mate selection, dominance tussles, and it's morphology may be designed to be vertically long and lower into the solar plexus.

There is a pit at the top of the sternum into which the chin fits when it is lowered.

Any kind of space under the chin can serve as leverage to push the head upwards and access the neck, so a chin that specificially points downwards flush with the solar chest and which deflects the arm upwards towards the mouth is an advantage to humans.

The chin size is promoted by testosterone which happens to be a hormote that encourages fighting.

The human chin is more powerful than in all other primates and can withstant more PSI force, which suggests that it is made to withstand a lot of clunking damage.

Actually 70 percent of paleolithic mandibular fractures could derive from fighting, that's in line with today's epedimeology figures, minus car accidents.

I believe that the chin comes from a range of selective factors, and i am curious about it's topological optimization, they precise shape and it's mechanical advantage. I believe that the current theories are true, and I wouldn't be surprised if the defense of westling positions can account for a lot of it's precise shape similar to a snow plough and it's alignment with the chest.

If any anthropologists are vaguely entertained by this theory the effectiveness of the chin in wrestling defense can be measured by studying archive of the number of successful defenses against wrestling strangleholds, which outnumber the attempts by 2-5.

*Mechanism of injury of mandible fracture patients. MVC Motor vehicle collision, GSW Gunshot wound*
[image]

To counter Johns odd claim about eye gouging as an alternative human wrestling action, punch damage accounts for 99% more hospital submissions than eye gouging.

Strangulation is unique to our species, so it is fitting to question: which hominids first used them? Was the bite force of a Neanderthal the previous best defense for choke holds? Is the Neanderthal physiology or mind not conducive to that kind of wrestling interaction? When did hominids develop aggression traits and cognitive forethought and a wiry physique that made choke holds possible?

Did the advent of a snowplow chin as a strangulation defense even facilitate the reduction of the jaw size of humans to it's present scale?

Anthropologically, human faces are not level with the genitals, as in dogs and monkeys, who inspect each other's genitals to gather information about their sexual state. Humans communicate with the eyes diverted towards the mouth, and face, they express their sexual state with mouth movements, side motions, and an array of gestures. The Chin also serves a display purpose in that end, so mechanical forces are not the only things that should be considered, but they count alot!! The development of complex facial expressions to describe sexual communication may have also encouraged the formation of a robust chin.

A lower and more forwards pointed chin protects the neck better, other animals develop pronounced features related to their rutting combats, crabs with a large arm, antlers, https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2012/07/120726142202.htm

Children learn head locks from an early age, head locks are a combat action singular to humans.

The human jaw is as strong or stronger than that of other primates. The incisors can deliver 70 PSI to the chin, and a human punch can deliver 1700 PSI. 6Mpa is about 800 pounds.

The chin serves as a crash guard to intercept whacks at the apex of the triangle, It is used as a life saving neck guard in the most common wrestling submission by providing no leverage under the jaw, and it is a masculin trait controlled by testosterone, quite contrary to the general neotenic traits of homo sapiens.

Comment: Chins developed *long* before humans (pretty much anything that has a lower jaw has a chin, even if it's hidden under soft flesh), so I doubt your hypothesis is correct.

Comment: Are you sure that your vote to close the question is not related to our heated disagreement on the other thread? you were inaccurate about the age of menarche, because you overlooked that urban medieval late development was due to malnutrition compared to paleolithic times. Again you are wrong about chins. The science correspondant from the BBC states: It becomes even stranger when you consider that among the all primates – including our extinct relatives – only we have chins. ... So honestly i believe that your comment is not related to actual knowledge and accuracy, which is quizzical.

Comment: it's hard for me to see how this could be tested ... what stops it from being an evolutionary Just-So story?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! indeed theories on primate orofacial anatomy are specialist post doctoral research topics, and i should read how their papers and measurements are constructed. From one of the postdoctoral journal articles i have just read:  The chin, however, appears to be a uniquely modern human trait. so, The question is open to scientific discussion, with much precedent, although my reasoning for it is perhaps a new one.

Comment: You should add a link in your question to the article you mention in the comment to @John answer, as well as the piece from [the Atlantic](http://www.theatlantic.com/notes/2016/01/no-really-other-animals-dont-have-chins/433890/) that it links to, to provide better context and a clearer definition of what aspects of the lower jaw you're talking about. A picture of a human skull would probably also be useful. If those articles are true (which I have no reason to doubt), the human chin does indeed seem quite unique.

Comment: The unique features of the jaw evolved at the same time our faces and jaws shrunk. humans cranial structure is unique in many ways.

Comment: That's a very good counter theory John. I believe that it probably has a fair statistical contribution to play for the reproduction advantage conveyed by the chin. If the chin plays an important role in human defense and male hyerarchy, and protects the neck from a mortal hold, i believe that it provides a statistical contribution to survival fitness too. The chin is actually a hook shape that hitches a forearm above the neck, and males don't need a larger and more hooked chin by Holton's theory. I added pics

Comment: I am curious why you think primitive weapons are unsuitable for combat? we have been hunting large game with spears long before we had chins.

Comment: Because combat with weapons is a declaration of intent to kill. humans think twice to compete for a woman with a stick. Combat within a tribe for a woman in heat is safer for all parties if it is a primate show of force. The advantage of against strangling is purveyed in all kinds of fighting. I was an adept fighter john i had some wrestler brothers. a bola or a spear and a rear ambush are dangerous to cavement, but a frontal mohawk attack is a joke. i can fling any mohawk, spear etc and catch it because it's inertial mass manipulated by the thin hand is very predictable. hands are agile.

Comment: @comprehensible I had forgotten all about that question. Votes are on the question, not the questioner. I still think this question is opinion-based, as the question "Why did this feature evolve like so?" Is almost impossible to answer.

Comment: Stackexchange is not a forum for extended discussions - it is in a question-answer format. This question seems to either look for the confirmation of a posed hypothesis or is discussion,  which to me would both seem off topic.

Answer (score 5):

No
We know why the chin exists, the jaw has to be strong to be stable and not twist during under strain. humans have tiny jaws, large tongues, and sharply angled neck that leaves no room for a large enough interior ridge, so the jaw has to protrude forward or get taller to compensate. Our large facial muscles and tongue encourage the former, as does the overall shrinking of the face and jaw. The development of the chin lines up perfectly with the shrinking of the jaw and face and expansion of the tongue in hominid evolution.

Now the size of the chin may very well be influenced by sexual selection, your hypothesis might even fall into this if you had any evidence. sexual selection could exaggerate it once present, but we know why the chin originates.Like everything in evolution there are multiple factors at play but you have yet to show yur ideas is even a factor much less an important one.

For your idea to hold water you need to show several things.

1. That headlocks are a significant and persistent problem in human history. Which is unlikely given how many skeletons are known that were killed with weapons.
2. That the chin actually does protect against it, especially more than say a wider neck or taller jaw, which we lost.
3. If it does help and headlocks were a significant problem, why does the size of the chin varies so much.
4. Why the chin develops so much later than the when the neck shrank, which is when humans would have started being vulnerable to headlocks.
5. That other explanations are not better supported.

Also there are lots of ways to kill someone while "wrestling", statistics from a sport competition with restrictive rules are not helping your case. I can't claw someone's eye out or stab them in the UFC.  And I want you to think of why a human seeking to kill another would forgo the many weapons they would have, to wrestle them instead. especially why this would would happen so often a defense would need to evolve.

[All you ever wanted to know about the chin](http://www.pitt.edu/~jhs/articles/human_chin_revisited.pdf)

Comment: From a survey of 40 people whose measurements were plotted from toddler to adults, researchers concluded that the mechanical forces needed to chew are incapable of producing the resistance needed for new bone to be created in the jaw area.
"In short, we do not find any evidence that chins are tied to mechanical function, and in some cases we find that chins are worse at resisting mechanical forces as we grow," Dr. Nathan Holton

Comment: @comprehensible, Dr Holton shows the chin is not an acquired characteristic which is very different from an evolutionary adaptation.

Comment: I would want to see a source for headlocks end a large majority of fights, especially in pre-industrial societies. ditto for the chin playing a part in defense in such cultures.  Statistics from sport fights with rules are pointless, I can't claw your eyes out or stab you in the UFC. And by your statement about men and women I'm guessing you did not read my statement about sexual selection.

Comment: Also not all primate males fight, but if you were right why would women have chins? sexual selection could explain the difference in sexes, we both use it after all)but if it was the only cause as you claim women should not develop chins. I also feel I should mention some neanderthal do have chins,

Comment: I am adding in some stuff from Holton's actaul published works, http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0306987706009091 where he shows the tongue is having more effect than bite forces.

Comment: You provide good arguements, thanks. There is a major disadvantage to the tonge reinforcement theory: There are zero chances of a human breaking his jaw from using his tongue forcefully and from chewing. In that sense, the reinforcement of the jaw is excessive. The tongue simply has never broken a single jaw in zero recorded humans, nor has chewing. The shape is reinforced for more brutal defense, and a fighting stress on the chin is hundreds of times larger than the pressures exerted by bite force etc. fighting has broken millions of jaws jaws and strangled millions of humans.

Comment: actually biting can injure the jaw. It doesn't happen much in developed countries becasue thanks to industrialization we have an abundance of calcium in our diets and eat really really soft foods.. To the point it often creates an overbite becasue the jaw is not stressed enough to induce proper development. But the biggest thing over flexing can cause is tooth loss and fracture.  And of course why would you expect the jaw to be damaged if we evolved improvements, a fractured jaw would be terminal in the wild so it should be overbuilt. So far my five points still stand.

Comment: HAHA! your are inventing now, your previous phrases were totally convincing and eloquent but that was not reasonable! the statistical death rate from jaw fracture on food compared to human attack and strangling are statistically microscopic. Find a single written example of a fractured jaw from biting? the break happens in the teeth, and the flexor muscles at the back tear and strain before the jaw fractures, on any food.

Comment: So humans need a proportionally larger base to support tiny teeth which work less? Irrational and inconclusive. The human teeth reduced because they didn't need to be as robust. you will find millions of articles concerning injury from strangling, and practically zero on injury from biting. the statistical bias is giant. You should find a single reference to jaw damage from biting, i belive that your comment about overbite stems from an inability to find any references of jaw fracture due to biteing.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I found a graph that of mandibular epidemiology (sounds cool?) which illustrates the strength of the chewing fracture argument as 0% of mandibular injuries. also, the fractures happen on the sides, not near the chin. ZERO PERCENT from a 181 patient study! that doesn't strengthen the logic that you defend. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2690628/

Comment: @comprehensible if you feel that you have enough sources to convincingly defend your hypothesis, then write an answer and let the voters decide who is correct. At this point, I feel that you are arguing just because you are so wedded to your hypothesis that you don't want to accept any opposing evidence, which is the opposite of how the scientific method is supposed to work. Additionally, your point about a lack of modern jaw fractures related to chewing doesn't make any sense - if we evolved to have a strong jaw/chin to prevent such injuries, then of course we won't suffer from them!

Comment: So,  I'm busy with geometry and it was only supposed to be a 46 word post to jot the theory online.. With your refutations to discourage further consideration of such a vast and curious thoery, and your and closure vote as an opening statement, you demonstrated the kind of lack of consideration which stifles science. Top scientists are ecouraged to use words like may, maybe, seems to, in my view, because stentor terminology to kick off a discussion results in a mess. Elder statemen qualify used terms in a way which gives the original speaker wise perspective on his possible misuse of words.

Comment: Darwin found 5 odd finches and turned his puzzle around from all angles to measure it's significance, and that's what i was hoping the forum would do. I don't care i have too many thoeries:). measure the idea from all angles and state the pros and cons. There's clearly about 3 factors that shaped the jaw bone, mostly defense related. A professional anthropologist is free to develop a statistically viable carachterization of this documented and life saving function of chin's precise jutting form. I'm fine to wait 20 years or never for a doc to shaft or clarify it. Its unstudied science!!! So

Comment: You can call zero percent incidence in an epedemiology a significant proportion, and fail to cite a single case worldwide of some enraged human cracking his jaw on pecan nut (recall that Dr Holton ruled out bite injury as the cause of hte chin, and suggestedthe tongue instead) ... I encourage you the best of luck to defend a zero incidence of records and a zero percent epidemeiology result. a jar reces which guides the arm towards the neck is not significant in a violent species... That's fine, It's not a very valuable technology to divest time on.

Comment: I asked them for a statistic to support their claim that chewing fractures are significant, to counter the statistic showing that collision causes 100 percent of the kinetic stress on the jaw... They refused to provide statistics and reference, so the comments dragged on. Do to their lack of statistics about kinetic stress from chewing compared to collusion, i consider that they have valiantly but totally lost the debate for lack of evidence.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50648/discussion-on-answer-by-john-can-the-human-chin-have-developed-to-protect-agains).

Comment: @comprehensible the discussion has been moved to chat. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50648/discussion-on-answer-by-john-can-the-human-chin-have-developed-to-protect-agains

Answer (score -2):

It's naive and wrong to state that the theories for the chin are agreed upon and and comprehended, else that protection from strangling is an impossibility in selective pressures which contribute to it's current shape:

[*Protective reinforcement of the hominin face*](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/brv.12112/abstract) is a [2014 study](http://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-27720617).

A search of google indicates that:

- "punched police report" returns 1mn results on google
- "choked police report" returns 7mn results on google
- "punching police report" returns 4mn results on google
- "choking police report" returns 14mn results on google

The previous answer is based on the impossibility that choking can be of any significance in human interaction. For the idea to have any merit, you would have to demonstrate that:

- Chokes contribute a few percent of human tribal fatalities or tribal mate choice.
- The downwards inflection of the bone is an arbitrary construction for reinforcement and display, and that it's non-arbitrary for protection of the larynx.

40-90% of street fights caught on camera ended up with [wrestling on the floor](https://jiujitsu365.wordpress.com/2008/03/11/do-most-fights-go-to-the-ground-research-i-conducted/). https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/1342/is-it-true-that-most-fights-end-on-the-ground-what-is-the-evidence

Neck constrictions end 70-80% of human wrestling fights, and are common in the schools.

John suggests that eye gouging can be a major statistical result in wrestling, however eye pokes only account for [1.7 to 2.1%](http://caribbean.scielo.org/img/revistas/wimj/v61n6/a09tab03.jpg) of all [eye traumas](http://jamanetwork.com/data/Journals/OPHTH/6633/ecs8224t2.png), which is of low significance including sport which contributes most of that 1.7%, compared to jaw fractures, 42% of which are caused by assault. [13% of eye traumas are from violence](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0048377), mostly from punching, but also from sticks bottles knives and weapons, and very few from fingers.

Men don't gouge their wives' eyes out in order to assert dominance in studies of domestic abuse.

> "... later than the when the neck shrank ...".

The musculature of the neck changed when humans became more gracile and lithe. Their necks allow them to play the piano and contributes to their intelligence and the [development of their brains](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2010/07/100727112833.htm).

Evolution of speech caused the hyoid bone to drop (which allows primates to breathe and drink at the same time, and prevents choking) and without the change of the larynx and the hyoid bone, we'd still garble and hoot much like our chimpanzee cousins, scientists say.

> "...why does the size of the chin varies..."

The growth and forwards slant of the chin ("mental eminence" from Menton, french) vary relative to testosterone, which is a fighting, sexual appetite, and strengthening hormone, though shape of the chin doesn't vary a lot. A large majority / all sapiens have a chin which does not allow leverage under the neck compared to ancestors. Neanderthals had much more of a chin than homo heidelbergensis.

*Here is an example of a skull of a man who was exposed to high levels of testosterone (right), compare to a females skull (left):*
[image]
[image: Ethnic differences of skull]
[image]

When the body was less gracile and more muscled, the arms were more articulated, Is when the chin was weaker in PSI resistance, and the superciliary arch and the skull was stronger.

Previous studies have shown that the chin could be due to a range of factors, and it might be wrong to say that defense is the only cause for selection.

It would be wrong to say that the selection pressure on the chin from fighting is known, and to say that we have measured the mechanics entirely, sexual selection is very closely associated with the chin, as women are interested in beard and chin size of males.

Comment: This could really use some sources to back up its claims, and meaningful claims made from the sources it does provide. Unfortunately, most of what you've put seems irrelevant, or requires heavy speculation and misunderstanding of context to approximate a valid affirmative answer.

Comment: You only have one citation, and that is behind a paywall. Please add support for each of the claims made here. *`"Scientists say"`* is not a citation.

Comment: Starting with your statement "humans aren't the only animals to have a chin, so i doubt your hypothesis is correct" your contribution to this page has shown a lack of intellectual accuracy which suggests that your access as a moderator on stack exchange is a matter of couchpotato attrition and not of intellectual depth. In biology, specific terms have specific meanings, so bipedal, chin, have established meanings. Elephants are accepted as having a chin. if you blur terminology, semantics degenerate into a dulled confused perception, i just had to embelish/improve that theory while at 41'C.

Comment: @comprehensible Your point about including unrelated chin examples has merit, but resist the temptation to lead that into speculative ad hominem attacks. It's a complete waste of time. Focus instead on finding strong evidence for your answer and/or deriving a strong answer from your evidence.

Comment: @Harris Weinstein, Sorry the phrases and stats are quoted from an array or results and surveys, i ll add the references, fair comment thanks.